# How can I make a UITableViewCell that changes text color but *not* background color on selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a plain old UITableViewCell that has black text, a dark background and separators above and below.

What I want is when the cell is highlighted or selected, the text turns green but nothing else changes. Is this possible without subclassing UITableViewCell? If not, what's the best way to make sure the subclass changes as little as possible?

Comment: Hi, really congrats to have reviewed again the answers. You made the right choice for your code. Enjoy!

Comment: Yeah, I agree that subclassing is the better way to go, but again, I was just answering your question... Glad you figured out a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Subclassing** the cell and **overriding** the method `setSelected:`.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    _myLabel.textColor = (selected) ? [UIColor orangeColor] : [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Comment: if you do this, then calling cell.selected will always return NO, right? (because you didn't call `[super]`)

Comment: yes i forgot to insert that line thanks ;) P.S. I didn't see you accepted the other response. I invite you to rethink on what approach to use because actually this is the best practice to sort it out.

Comment: FYI As written, your answer won't work for several reasons... (1) The method is actually supposed to be - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated; not - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected , (2) although the the text will change color when selected the first time, it won't change back when selected the second time, (3) and adding the [super setSelected:selected]; line seems to repeatedly force calls to setSelected:... This answer needs a lot of work unfortunately...

Comment: Yes I forgot ANIMATED and so :D ?! It is the solution the important thing! There is the documentation to see that there is another parameter it is not certain this the important thing! And also who told you that the user needs to select and deselect with another click on the same cell?! The normal behaviour it is just select a cell and when select another cell the tableView automatically call `setSelected:NO aimated:..` on the previous cell.

Comment: @MatteoGobbi Now that you've made those changes, your answer mostly works, but the background color is being grayed out after being selected. So you should factor that in to have your answer be a bit more correct. Otherwise congrats! Your answer is now much better after your update.

Comment: @MatteoGobbi Is this line Obj-C? `_myLabel.textColor = (selected) ? [UIColor orangeColor] : [UIColor blackColor];` Or Swift?

Comment: objc. It is just an in-line ***if statement***. This approach is usable in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible without subclassing your cell. (FYI typing this out on my phone now, so this answer may has some mistakes...but I think the general idea is right...)

First off, set cell's selection style to "none" to prevent the background color from changing upon selection. Secondly, set your label's text color in cellForRowAtIndexPath depending on whether the cell is selected, ex:

```
NSMutableArray *selectedCells;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    selectedCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // ... Create cell ...
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    if ([selectedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    // ...the other code...
}

// If a cell's selected add it to the selectedCells array, if
// deselected, remove it; then reload the table
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([selectedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [selectedCells removeObject:indexPath];
    } else {
        [selectedCells addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: absolutely this is not the right way to do it. It is exactly what I call a "patch" and wrong approach more expensive of what it is.

Comment: @MatteoGobbi The question was "Is this possible without subclassing UITableViewCell?" and this offers a solution without using subclasses.

Comment: @MatteoGobbi (Note: Since the answer to "Is this possible without subclassing UITableViewCell?" is yes, the "if not" statement isn't reached. So I answered the OP's question.)